# How do I change the width of the country picker in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, country-codes

- I am implementing country code picker and mobile number field.
- How do I change the size of the country picker so that both the country picker and the mobile number text field are properly place.
- Code is as follow

```
Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          //SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                          child: CountryPicker(
                            dense: true,
                            showFlag: false, //displays flag, true by default
                            showDialingCode:true, //displays dialing code, false by default
                            showName: true, //displays country name, true by default
                            showCurrency: false, //eg. 'British pound'
                            showCurrencyISO: false,
                            onChanged: (Country country) {
                              setState(() => _selected = country);
                              print(country.dialingCode);
                              countryCode = country.dialingCode;
                              },
                            selectedCountry: _selected,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          //SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                          child: TextFormField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Mobile no.',
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            ),
                            validator: (val) => val.length != 10
                                ? 'Enter a mobile number of 10 digits'
                                : null,
                            onChanged: (val) {
                              setState(() => phone = val);
                              phoneno = phone;
                              },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
```

- Image is attached below
  [image]

Comment: Maybe you can give more details what you understand as "properly" .. But why not just remove the `Expanded` around the countrypicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give first `Expanded` widget the flex value of 1 and second `Expanded` 3.

What happens is that the width gets divided into 4 equal parts (1+3), and 1 part is occupied by the first `Expanded` widget, and the remaining 3 parts get occupied by second `Expanded` widget. You can play around various proportions to meet your UI needs.

```
Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                //SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                child: CountryPicker(
                  dense: true,
                  showFlag: false, //displays flag, true by default
                  showDialingCode:
                      true, //displays dialing code, false by default
                  showName: true, //displays country name, true by default
                  showCurrency: false, //eg. 'British pound'
                  showCurrencyISO: false,
                  onChanged: (Country country) {
                    setState(() => _selected = country);
                    print(country.dialingCode);
                    countryCode = country.dialingCode;
                  },
                  selectedCountry: _selected,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                //SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Mobile no.',
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  ),
                  validator: (val) => val.length != 10
                      ? 'Enter a mobile number of 10 digits'
                      : null,
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(() => phone = val);
                    phoneno = phone;
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply wrap your widget in containers with width without `Expanded`. This is the code I used with device width

```
Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3.7,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                            child: CountryPicker(
                              dense: true,
                              showFlag: false, //displays flag, true by default
                              showDialingCode:
                                  true, //displays dialing code, false by default
                              showName:
                                  true, //displays country name, true by default
                              showCurrency: false, //eg. 'British pound'
                              showCurrencyISO: false,
                              onChanged: (Country country) {
                                setState(() => _selected = country);
                                print(country.dialingCode);
                                countryCode = country.dialingCode;
                              },
                              selectedCountry: _selected,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.6,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Mobile no.',
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                              ),
                              validator: (val) => val.length != 10
                                  ? 'Enter a mobile number of 10 digits'
                                  : null,
                              onChanged: (val) {
                                setState(() => phone = val);
                                phoneno = phone;
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
```